# Community Supported Virtual HDD Ubuntu Configured for VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

There are some websites which hosts some virtual HDD images of Ubuntu configured for VirtualBox, without need of installation. 
However, I cannot trust them without community support.

Is there any community supported virtual HDD images of Ubuntu configured for VirtualBox?

Is there any virtual HHD Ubuntu supported by community and configured by Vagrant?

Comment: You so not need any special Ubuntu image to install it in VB. What is your question? Just install normal Ubuntu image.

Comment: @Pilot6 I want it to be configured for the VB so we would have a standard image for it.

Comment: Then install yourself ubuntu in VB with an iso and you will get your image ?

Comment: @Pilot6 OP talks about virtual HDD image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). This is a super easy way to create and work with VM's and [Ubuntu releases images](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu) that are scrutinized and used by thousands of developers.

Using vagrant is super easy.

1. Install vagrant 
   `apt-get install vagrant`
2. Add a box of the distro you want 
   `vagrant box add trusty/amd64`
3. Start the VM 
   `vagrant up`

UPDATE:

For a simple example check out this project on github. https://github.com/levlaz/braindump

1. The Vagrantfile installs the VM, syncs folders, forwards ports, and runs a bootstrap.sh script that installs some additional packages in Ubuntu.
2. The bootstrap.sh is a simple bash script that installs some packgages, and performs various configurations.

Comment: Nice idea! Vagrant can create a virtual machine. Can you, give an example, how you can automatize the configuration of Ubuntu with it, please.

Comment: Sure thing check out this github repo where I have a script called bootstrap.sh that installs some packages that I need and starts a python web application. https://github.com/levlaz/brainadump The Vagrantfile defines the distro and the bootstrap file and the bootstrap.sh file does everything else. You can also forward ports and folders  to access the VM as if it was your local computer.

Comment: @Masi, Sorry about that looks like the URL was wrong! I updated the answer with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an Ubuntu Virtual Image created and supported by Canonical for VirtualBox.

If you want 100% trustworthiness, download Ubuntu and create the image yourself.

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask